# Iterating when using OptimizeForPointLookup

Tags: rocksdb

I have a requirement where I only do point lookups but I also need to iterate but don't have to be in any specific order. I used OptimizeForPointLookup and used the iterator API and everything seems to work fine. However, the rocksdb code is documented with the following in options.h against the OptimizeForPointLookup api.

// Use this if you don't need to keep the data sorted, i.e. you'll never use
// an iterator, only Put() and Get() API calls

Is there something I am missing? Interestingly the iteration also seems to be happening in a sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

OptimizeForPointLookup() API makes the GET/PUT operation faster by creating a `BLOOM FILTER` and setting the Index type to `kHashSearch`. As the name suggest, `kHashSearch` creates hash over the keys and makes point lookups faster.

For normal iterator operation, the index type is set to `kBinarySearch`.
RocksDB by default, inserts data into memtable in sorted order. Optimizing for Point Lookups doesnot affect this insert behaviour of rocksDB.